# React updating array in useState hook and getting new length

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of images and then when the user performs an action, like, clicking a button, or dragging a photo to the screen, I add the photo my array.

```
let newImageList = [...imageList, {src: src, status: 0}]
        
setImageList(newImageList)

let lastIndex = imageList.length
console.log("last index of image list:", lastIndex)
```

Two things are messed up:

1. The index never increases
2. My imageList doesn't appear to update either.

However, when I do it this way...

```
 setImageList(prevArray => [...prevArray, {src: src, status: 0}])

 let lastIndex = imageList.length
 console.log("last index of image list:", lastIndex)
```

Then the imageList does update (I see it later in my html where I show the images in the list), but again the lastIndex doesn't change ever.

**What I Want**

The expected behaviour is that the imageList would grow and I would be able to get the last index from it.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `react` is asynchronous, so when you're trying get `imageList.length` exactly after `setImageList`, you maybe see the unupdated `state`. You need to call a callback function for getting the correct `state` after update. For this purpose you don't need anything in classify component which are `statefull`, because `setState` in classify components have callback function. But if you're using functional component, you need to add a callback function to the `setImageList`. You can use [use-state-with-callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-with-callback) third party library. Instead of `react`'s default `useState` you can use `useStateWithCallback`:

```
const [imageList,setImageList] = useStateWithCallback([],()=>{
  let lastIndex = imageList.length
  console.log("last index of image list:", lastIndex)
});
```